# Count number of times a button was pressed in 15 minute chunks

Tags: java, android, csv, hashmap, counter

My application has 24 buttons to count different vehicle types and directions (the app will be used to count traffic). Currently, I'm saving a line to a .csv file each time a button is pressed. The csv file contains a timestamp, direction, etc.

I have to measure how many times every button was pressed in 15-minute intervals.

How should I store the counters for the buttons?
I just need to output how often every button (every button has a different tag for identification) was pressed in 15 minutes.

I was thinking about using a HashMap, which could just take the button's tag as key and the number of occurrences as value, like this:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

Integer value = (Integer) hm.get(buttonTag);
    if (value == null) {
        hm.put(buttonTag, 1);
    } else {
        int nr_occ = value.intValue() + 1;
        hm.put(buttonTag, nr_occ);
    }
```

However, I don't need the total sums of button presses, but in 15 minute chunks. And as I'm already writing timestamps to the raw csv-file, I'm wondering how I should store these values.

Edit: I'm currently testing the HashMap, and it's working really well for counting, but I see two issues: first of all, grouping it into 15-minute intervals and secondly, the hashmap isn't sorted in any way. I'd need to output the values sorted by vehicle types and directions.

Comment: Are you referring to the way to store the counters in memory while the app is being used? If so, do you need to also display the counters from the previous runs of your app?

Comment: I just need to store the counters while the app is in use, the counters from previous runs are irrelevant.

Comment: Use a static int and count it up every time the button is pressed.

Comment: So what you're saying is I should store 24 different ints for every button and count those up? How would you then implement the grouping into 15-minute intervals?

Comment: @iDroid what happens when they get an hour long phone call and the activity is destroyed? The static int goes bye bye.

Comment: haha, well I am developing this for a tablet, which would only be used for counting traffic, so phone calls wouldn't even be an issue here.

Comment: @Emanuel ok the user happens to hit the Home button... not saying it actually would but at that point, even if only for a nanosecond, your activity is marked as being able to be destroyed by the system. Again losing any active data not stored.

Comment: And SharedPreferences would be preserverd, the user enters the app again, finishes his counting session, hits the Stop button and all is well? That sounds perfect!

Comment: Anyone want to comment on the serialization approach? It seems strange putting non-preferences in SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is simple (i.e. you only need a key/value pair) then consider using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store the button id and the time it was pressed.

This is a good way because it is extremely fast. You already put the info into a .csv file but to extract the data and traverse through it so that you can compare timestamps is too much overhead IMO.

When a button is pressed store your data in the .csv file then also store the key/value (id/timestamp) then you can iterate through that and do your compare and output whatever you need to output.

The other way (and probably even better) is to simply create and write to your .csv file, then dump it and use something else more robust to process that data as you will probably be doing this anyway.

EDIT: I see a lot of answers which are saying to use SQLite, statics, etc...

These are all inferior methods for what you are asking. Here is why...
SQLite is WAY too much for just a simple button id and timestamp. However if you think you might need to store more data in the future this may in fact be an option.

A static variable might be destroyed if the system happens to destroy the Activity.

Comment: Well I have to store the timestamp, direction, turn and vehicletype. Currently (direction,turn,vehicletype) is the button's tag.

How could I process the raw data from the csv file? I'd would be great for my client if they got the counts off of the device, without having to run a script or something. But how would I go about processing the data?

Comment: @Emanuel still though you are saying you only need an identifier and a value. This is where SharedPreferences shine IMO. You could even clear it quickly every fifteen minutes if you want and start writing to it again and just count how many matches for each identifier.

Comment: About the SQLite, I tried doing it with SQLite but just like you say, it's really complex for this relatively simple task. And I'm a 100 percent sure that we won't need to store more data in the future. About the SharedPreferences: So I'd store the button's tag as key, the timestamp as value. Then I'd count how many occurence in a 15-minute window are there, and process these? And I'd delete the preferences when the user clicks a stop button? Would this suffice?

Comment: And another question, I've already used SharedPreferences once to store which buttons are enabled/disabled. I can just create another SharedPreferences object, correct?

Comment: Pretty much... I would make one change though... I would go ahead and clear the file at the START of whenever you need it. This is because you may never have a chance to clear the file before the app is closed, thus if you assume it is clear when you begin writing to it you may have old stale data.

Comment: You create a new file when you instantiate the preference handler. You can have as many files as you need.

Comment: thanks for that suggestion. Would you store the time as String and use a SimpleDateFormat or store it as Int (seconds since ....)? When thinking about it, just adding 900 seconds to the int would be perfect to get the chunks of data.

Comment: Store the timestamp by using something like: final long _currentTime = java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis(); then knowing that 15 mins is 900,000 milliseconds just subtract your stored value from the current time and is that number > 900,000ms ... btw this thing is heavily encouraging me to move this into a chat... It says that you don't have enough rep to move to a chat. If you are interested I can help you with the details just hit me up.

Comment: Alright, thank you so much! It's also encouraging me, even though I'm 5 rep short to chat. I'd gladly accept your offer, how can I contact you until I get the 5 rep?

Comment: Alright, I'll send you an email! If you'd like you can now delete your comment, so your email adress is safe.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be **cool**, just serialise the `HashMap` every time your activity gets destroyed (`onDestroy`) and load it back up when your activity gets created (`onCreate`). This is going to be the quickest and simplest way.

Where are you serializing your data to? To a file in `Environment.getExternalStorage()`.

Oh and you might want to keep track of a timestamp to clear the `HashMap` every 15 minutes - you could put this in `SharedPreferences`.

I assume you already know how to do this but just in case: [Java Serialization](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/)

Comment: Sorry for this question, but why would I need to serialise the HashMap? Because I have no idea how I'd actually count the 15-minute chunks - serialised or not.

Comment: Then make it a HashMap of lists (or arrays or just make a 2-dimensional array)! Use a timestamp + System.currentTimeInMillis() to figure out which index we're on. Then you can make pretty graphs. Whole serialization process is to preserve your 'simple' data (whatever that may be) if your application is destroyed.

Comment: So I'd use the serialization to make sure the data stays there in case the application is closed. How would this HashMap of Lists look like? I assume the HashMap would contain the button's tag as key and the list would contain the timestamp?

Comment: Question first, how long do you want to keep this data around for?

Comment: I'd only have to store the data until the user stops his counting session. However, it would be great if the data could be preserved when the user accidentally closes the app. But I only need to store it until the user stops and the data has been written to a file.

Comment: Yes so when the user presses 'Start' you record the current system time to SharedPreferences (to persist the value). For each button press you look at this value minus the current time and divide by 15 minutes to find which 15 minute slot we're in. Now that we know what slot we're in, update the count in the hashmap in the right index on the list (the list index now represents 15 minute count blocks). Press stop, write to csv, clear all data, done.

Comment: This sounds really great, I'll try to implement it tomorrow when I'm at work. You really have been a huge help.

Answer (score 0):

Might be me but this sounds as an ideal situation for using a SQLite database. So you can easily get this interval thing from that by selecting on the timestamp.

Comment: I already tried doing it with a SQLite database, but I got to say that I was a little overwhelmed, as I'm not at all experienced with Android Development. But I'm really starting to think that SQLite would really be the perfect choice. 

Can you help me with the database?
I think I'd need to create a new table on every app-start and store this data: id,date,time,vehicletype,direction,turn. And then select the data I need and write the data to a new csv file?